# Rails and Heroku - Destroy a single record from production database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is it possible to destroy a single record from my production PG database using an ActiveRecord command from my console?  I know that I can do this locally by simply running the following command in my Rails console:

```
> User.find(1).destroy
```

However, I have tried running this for my production db:

```
> heroku run rake User.find(1).destroy
```

But it does not work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: _"Does not work"_?  You'll have to explain further, and also explain why you think it should work (do you have the correct permissions)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the console on heroku first with:

```
$ heroku run rails console
```

Then you can delete the record with the same query:

```
> User.find(1).destroy
```

If there are multiple apps configured from your folder, you will have to specify the app with `--app=<app name>` in the heroku command line:

```
$ heroku run rails console --app=<app name>
```

Comment: Dude - you rock!  I knew it would be something simple and I was trying to avoid running SQL.  Thanks so much for the quick response as well!

Answer (score 1):

its possible that you need to specify the app you are running. In that case it would be

```
heroku run console -a app_name
User.find(1).destroy
```